# Is it possible to reset xlim and ylim on an existing plot in R?

Tags: r, plot

I am reading a series of data files, performing computations on them, and then overlaying them onto the same plot. Based on the result of the computation, I need to set the upper bound of the `xlim` on the plot, if it is not already large enough.

However, I cannot know before performing the computation what the maximum upper bound will be.
Since the files are large, I'd prefer not to perform all the computations to discover the maximum upper bound before plotting anything.

Thus, I wonder if there is a way to set `xlim` after the first plot command has been called.

Comment: No, you have to replot everything if you want to change the axis limits.

Comment: @Roland within limits you can use the `zoom` package to change them. Meanwhile, merlin, what's your concern-- are you going to run out of memory if you store all the outputs? Typically there's little use to plotting that much data (the eye can't discriminate anyway), so you might want to reduce your datasets via binning&averaging.

Comment: The x-limit won't depend on the computations, at least if you are plotting some computed f(x) as a function of x. So look at your data first and set a sensible xlim.

Comment: At any rate the ggplot2 package would allow you to extend limits, albeit with the cost of having much bigger plot objects, since all the data is added to the object.